# Librosa help to read the audio file but in my case when I give input to the file name its shows run time error path not found

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a project but my problem is that my librosa library shows me that the file was not found, but it is present.

```
# Load using Librosa
y, sr = librosa.load(normal_file, duration=5)   #default sampling rate is 22 HZ     
dur=librosa.get_duration(y)
print ("duration:", dur)
print(y.shape, sr)
```

The error:

```
FileNotFoundError

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-d400d9a9c828> in <module>()
      1 # Load using Librosa
----> 2 y, sr = librosa.load(normal_file)   #default sampling rate is 22 HZ
      3 dur=librosa.get_duration(y)
      4 print ("duration:", dur)
      5 print(y.shape, sr)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    117 
    118     y = []
--> 119     with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
    120         sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    121         n_channels = input_file.channels

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py in audio_open(path, backends)
    105     """
    106     if backends is None:
--> 107         backends = available_backends()
    108 
    109     for BackendClass in backends:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py in available_backends()
     84 
     85     # FFmpeg.
---> 86     if ffdec.available():
     87         result.append(ffdec.FFmpegAudioFile)
     88 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\ffdec.py in available()
    106         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    107         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
--> 108         creationflags=PROC_FLAGS,
    109     )
    110     proc.wait()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\audioread\ffdec.py in popen_multiple(commands, command_args, *args, **kwargs)
     92         cmd = [command] + command_args
     93         try:
---> 94             return subprocess.Popen(cmd, *args, **kwargs)
     95         except OSError:
     96             if i == len(commands) - 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    707                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:
    711             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    995                                          env,
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
    998             finally:
    999                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

It shows duration and reads the audio file.